# compiler error by function application

Tags: haskell

I am trying to learn haskell and could not configure it out, why following code snippet can not get compiled:

```
*Uncurry> applyTwice f x = f f x

<interactive>:14:20: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t ~ t -> t2 -> t1
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: f f x
      In an equation for ‘applyTwice’: applyTwice f x = f f x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: t2 (bound at <interactive>:14:14)
        f :: t -> t2 -> t1 (bound at <interactive>:14:12)
        applyTwice :: (t -> t2 -> t1) -> t2 -> t1
          (bound at <interactive>:14:1)
```

This would be fine:

```
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

In haskell function application is left associative, the first code snippet would be apply like:

```
(f f) x
```

why `(f f) x` it is wrong?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Is your question "why `f f` is wrong?" Is it "why `f f x` means `(f f) x` and not `f (f x)`"? Something else?

Comment: The type of `f` would have to be `((((…) -> a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b`.

Comment: @n.m I mean why `f f x` is wrong.

Comment: If `f f x` was meaningful, i.e. `(f f) x` made sense, what would `f f` mean, on its own? If e.g. `f :: Int -> Int`, then `f 42` is an integer. But, `f` is not an integer (it's a function), so I can not pass it as the argument of `f` itself.

Comment: @chi So it is not like a higher order function?

Comment: Maybe `f` is higher order, but the types likely wouldn't match anyway. Application is not associative.

Answer (score 5):

If `f f` were valid, what would the type of `f` be?

We're applying `f` to an argument, so `f` has to be a function: `f :: a -> b` for some types `a`, `b`.

The argument we're applying the function to is `f`, so its type has to be `a`: `f :: a` (i.e. we have `(f :: a -> b) (f :: a)`).

Because both of these are the same `f`, we get `a -> b = a`. If `a` is the same as `a -> b`, then we can substitute `a` in and `a -> b` is the same as `(a -> b) -> b`, which is the same as `((a -> b) -> b) -> b`, etc.

This expansion never finishes and that's why ghc complains about `f` having an "infinite type".

Comment: Can you please explain it with lambda calculus?

Comment: @zero_coding Plain lambda calculus doesn't have a type system, so how would that work?

Comment: @zero_coding: Just look at the part with the title "Looking at the types" of my (long) post, there is a step-by-step explanation, let me quote myself:

If we really use f f x, then the type of f must satisfy these requirements:

    f must match the function type a -> a as specified in the type signature of applyTwice

    In f f f is applied to itself and that means that the a in a -> a must be equal to a -> a, which is impossible!

Comment: @melpomene why after first substitution is not finished `(a -> b) -> b`?

Comment: @zero_coding Because there's still an `a` in there. The equation is now `a = (a -> b) -> b` and it's trying to solve for `a`.

Comment: @melpomene where the `a` comes from? Help me please to understand it.

Comment: Why is `a` still there after substitution.

Comment: @zero_coding Why wouldn't it be there? What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: @melpomene For me, it is not clear at all, why it is infinite. After `(a -> b) -> b` there is no more something to substitute. Why can I still apply it?

Answer (score 3):

`f f x` means you want to pass `f` and `x` to `f`.

You need to ensure `f x` is evaluated first so only 1 argument is passed to the left-most `f`.

You can do that by wrapping it in  parentheses as you found out, or by using the application operator (both are effectively equivalent in this scenario):

```
f (f x) 
f $ f x
```

Answer (score 2):

> why (f f) x it is wrong?

Good question, I don't think it is *completely* wrong, I will try to rescue it, later!

But, I like to explain some basic concepts first.

I understand that the task is, to create a function `applyTwice` that applies any function given to it to the second parameter and then again to the result, right?

If you actually think about the concrete examples of functions given to `applyTwice` you might notice, that **not all functions can be applied twice**, for example, a function that converts a `Bool` to a `String`:

```
boolToString :: Bool -> String
boolToString True = "yes!!1eleven"
boolToString False = "ohnoes"
```

Can only be applied **exactly once**: After `boolToString` was applied to a `Bool`, we get a `String`, and we cannot apply `boolToString` again to its' result, since it does not accept a `String` as input.

What have the types of all those functions in common, that we can `applyTwice`?

Easy: The **input** has the **same type** as the **output**.

Examples for such functions:

```
increment :: Int -> Int
increment x = x + 1

appendDot :: String -> String
appendDot str = str ++ "."
```

BTW: functions type signatures are written with an arrow `->` like `input -> output` in Haskell.

Also, we can not only use **concrete types** like `String` or `Int` in type signatures, but also **type variables**.

Type variables always **start** with a **small letter** and concrete types with a capital letter.

A single type variable stands for an arbitrary type, and in the scope where it is used it can only stand for that one, selected type, no matter which one.

Now the concrete function types `String -> String` or `Int -> Int` match the general type:

```
 a -> a
```

This matches **all functions with the same input as ouput**.

And now we can get closer to the type of the `applyTwice` function:

```
 applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a 
 applyTwice    f           x  = f (f a)
```

The first part in brackets `(a -> a)` is actually the type of the function `f`, that is applied twice.

I hope you realize how *abstract* this `applyTwice` function really is:

It can work with **all** functions that have a **type matching `a -> a`**, i.e. *functions, where the input and output types are the same*

So we can give `increment` as well as `addDot` to `applyTwice`.

For example, let's create a new function `incTwice` that increments some number twice.

And of course we want to use our new tool `applyTwice` to built upon `increment` for this - in general one nice thing about Haskell is how elegantly we can re-combine and re-use small functions, like they were Lego-pieces:

```
 incTwice :: Int -> Int
 incTwice = applyTwice increment
```

Some interesting side points:

1. Notice, the type signature of `incTwice`: `Int -> Int`.

When `applyTwice` is applied to `increment` Haskell matchs the type `a` with `Int`.

So in that situation, in `incTwice` Haskell treats `applyTwice` like it has the concrete type `(Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int` .

2. Also notice that the type of `incTwice` is `Int -> Int`, which this means, that we can also apply `applyTwice` to it, to get back a function that adds four to a number, and that this function would also have the type `Int -> Int`, which we could infinitely often `applyTwice` with.

This is not only true for this example, notice how in general every function in Haskell that can be `applyTwice`-ed can be applied infinitely often!

### Let's look at some Haskell syntax!

I will try to shortly describe some more Haskell syntax.

Parentheses in Haskell define the composition of sub-expression to expressions or - another way to look at it - the decomposition of  expressions into sub-expressions.

Examples:

```
    ((1 - 1) * 10)      
    >>> 0
```

is an expression composed of the sub expression `*` applied to the sub-expression `(1 - 1)` and the sub-expression `10`, and `(1 - 1)` is also composed of the sub-expression `-` appplied to the sub-expressions `1` and `1`.

This could be written as a tree:

((1 - 1) * 10):

```
         (*)
        /   \
       /     \
     (-)     10
    /   \
   /     \
  1      1
```

which be the way is totally different to

```
    (1 - (1 * 10))
    >>> -9
```

which has the tree:

```
         (-)
        /   \
       /     \
      1      (*)
            /   \
           /     \
          1      10
```

Parentheses are also used in type definitions, to describe *function* types.
If no parentheses are given, the type `a -> b -> c -> d` would implicitly correspond to `a -> (b -> (c -> d))`, i.e. `->` is **right associative**,
which is the reason, that we have to use extra parentheses to indicate a function parameter!

Example function types:

- `(a -> b) -> c -> d` is the type of a function that takes a function of 
  type `a -> b` as parameter and returns a new function of type `c -> d`
- `(a -> b) -> (c -> d)` is the same as `(a -> b) -> c -> d` ;)
- `(a -> b -> c) -> d` is the type of a function that takes a function of type `a -> b -> c` as parameter and returns a value of type `d`
- `a -> (b -> c) -> d` is the type of a function that takes a value of type `a` and then a function of type `b -> c` as parameter and returns a value of type `d`
- `a -> (b -> (c -> d))` is the type of a function that takes a value of type `a` and then returns a new function, that takes a value of type `b` and returns a new function that takes a value of type `c` and returns a value of type `d`. This is the same as `a -> b -> c -> d`!

As you can see, explicit/extra parentheses can always be added and as long as they do not deviate from the implicit grouping, they always preserve the meaning of the expression/type,
so for example you could add extra parentheses around `1 + 1` like e.g. `((((1 + 1))))` or
`((((1)) + ((((1))))))`, without altering the meaning.

In general the Haskell2010 report [states](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-380003.9):

> Translation: `(e)` is equivalent to `e`.

One aspect that governs the implicit grouping of expressions into sub-expressions is called **associativity**.

The expression:

```
    1 - 1 - 1 - 1
```

could *in theory* mean **two** different things, depending on how the implied grouping of the sub expressions is.

If the implicit grouping would be as if parentheses were set like this:

1. `((1 - 1) - 1) - 1`, the expression had value `-2`,

on the other hand, if the implied grouping would be is if parentheses were set like this:

2. `1 - (1 - (1 - 1))`, the expression had value `0`!

The Haskell standard (called the *Haskell2010 Report*) mandates that the operator `-` **prefers to group with the numbers left of it**, so `1 - 1 - 1 - 1` is interpreted as `((1 - 1) - 1) - 1`.

Saying exactly this, but using the terminology of the Haskell report:

Operator `-` is *left associative*.

For entertaining, have a look at the [corresponding table](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-820061) in the Haskell2010 report.

The Haskell2010 report also contains the definition for the rules of [function application](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3):

> Function application is written `e1 e2`. Application **associates to the left**, 
>   so the parentheses may be omitted in `(f x) y`.

Which we will need to understand `(f f) x` vs. `f (f x)`.

Now that we have looked up in the Haskell2010 Report, that **function application** is **left associative**, we know that `f f x` is interpreted as `(f f) x`.

Also we read that **`(e)` is translated to `e`**.

After thinking a lot, one might see, that from this follows that `(f f) x` simply means:

```
**first** apply `f` to `f` and then apply _that_ to `x`.
```

Now, we are ready to ...

#### Comparing `(f f) x` and `f (f x)` by looking at the sub-expressions

Let's try to fully understand what `(f f) x` means, and what the difference to `f (f x)` is, and that they are **not the same expressions**.

On way to describe the difference between the expression `(f f) x` and`f (f x)` is too look at the sub-expressions of these expressions:

`f (f x)` can be written more explicit as this:

```
 let 
     intermediateResult = f x
     finalResult        = f intermediateResult

 in finalResult
```

with an expression tree that looks like:

```
            finalResult
                  =
                apply
              /       \
             /         \
            /           \
           f       intermediateResult      
                          =
                        apply
                      /       \
                     /         \
                    f           x
```

Whereas `(f f) x` means:

```
 let 
     intermediateFunction = f f
     finalResult          = intermediateFunction x

 in finalResult
```

The expression tree would be:

```
            finalResult
                  =
                apply
              /       \
             /         \
            /           \
 intermediateFunction    x
          =
        apply
      /       \
     /         \
    f           f
```

Clearly, as you can see from the expression trees, these are different expressions.
Or, one could argue that we cannot find any syntactic transformation (e.g. in the Haskell Report), converts back and forth between these expressions, without changing their meaning.

#### Looking at the types

I also want to demonstrate another approach at reasoning about the differences between `f f x` and `f (f x)`.

This approach consists of showing how `f f x` is an **incorrect** implementation of `applyTwice` while `f (f x)` is a **correct** implementation, by showing how `f f x` contradicts the type signature of `applyTwice`.

It might be hard to realize at first, but an important observation is that the type signature of `applyTwice`, i.e. `(a -> a) -> a -> a` is the **only reasonable type signature** that `applyTwice` could possibly have. If it were any different, it cound not possibly be a valid signature of our beloved `applyTwice` function, at least not as we know it, and with the order and number of parameters it takes - obviously (I hope).

So, if we simply show, that `f f x` has *just a different type* than `f (f x)`, we know, that `f f x` must be an *incorrect* implementation of `applyTwice`.

In General: The type checker in Haskell is a powerful tool to check if a program is broken, and
**sometimes it is even enough to look at the type of a function to learn what it does.**

Ok, on with the journey:

Let's try out what happens to the type signature of `applyTwice` if we would use `f f x` as function body, inplace of `f (f x)`.

Not only will the beast have a different type - which would already be enough to show that it is *wrong* since there is only one correct type signature for `applyTwice` (I challenge you, to come up with another type signature that is not wrong!) - it will also have an impossible to construct, infinite type!

Ok, remember the type signature for `f` in `applyTwice`: `(a -> a)`,
again, this means `f` has the same input type as output type.

Also the input value `x` (the second parameter of `applyTwice`) also has that (input/output-) type.

**Now** here comes the problem: If we really use `f f x`, then the type of `f` must satisfy these requirements:

1. `f` must match the function type `a -> a` as specified in the type signature of `applyTwice`
2. In `f f` `f` is applied to itself and that means that the `a` in `a -> a` must be equal to `a -> a`, which is impossible!

Ok, maybe this is not soo clear, let's look at it from a different angle.

1. Remember that `x` is bound to the type `a` by the type signature of `applyTwice`, which is the input (and ouput-) type of `f`,
2. The type signatures states that `f` has type `a -> a`,
3. Since `f f` is applied to `x`, and because the output of `applyTwice` is just `a`, the output type of `f f` must be `a -> a` and `x` would need to have to have type `a`
4. but since in `f f` `f` is applied to a function `a -> a`, `f` would need to have the type `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)`, and
5. since to is applied to itself, it would then need to have type `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))`
6. since to is applied to itself, it would then need to have type `(((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))) -> (((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a)))`
7. ...and so on till the end of times.

This is why the compiler complains about not being able to construct an infinite type.

```
   badApplyTwice :: ???? 
   badApplyTwice f x = (f f) x -- error cannot construct infinite type!
```

### Outside `applyTwice`, `(f f) x` is not wrong, only boring...

The problem that the compiler creates an infinite type roots in how the compiler tries to **bind** `a` to a single type, that will used throughout the whole expression, and makes every sub-expression happy.

But is `(f f)` wrong also outside of `applyTwice`?

No!

Let's use GHCi and define an `f` with the type `a -> b`:

```
 λ> :{
 λ| let f :: a -> b
 λ|     f = undefined
 λ| :}
```

Please note that multi-line expressions in GHCi are written with enclosed in `:{` ... `:}`.

... ok now with `:t` ghci show the type of any expression:

```
 λ> :t f
 f :: a -> b
```

... the type of `f f` is `b`:

```
 λ> :t (f f)
 (f f) :: b
```

So, if we define `f` like in `applyTwice` as `a -> a` then we see that `f f` has type `a -> a`:

```
 λ> :{
 λ| let f :: a -> a
 λ|     f = undefined
 λ| :}         
 λ> :t (f f)
 (f f) :: a -> a
```

Why? The type of `f x` with `f :: a -> a` is always `a`, since we always get back the type we put into `f` (input- and output type are identical), and since `f f` is actually like `f x` with `x` being `f`, we get the type of `f` which is `a -> a`.

So, what is the type of `(f f) x` then?

Well it is whatever concrete type `x` is. Let's use ghci again, and look at some examples:

```
λ> :t (f f) 3
(f f) 3 :: Num a => a

λ> :t (f f) True
(f f) True :: Bool

λ> :t (f f) "test"
(f f) "test" :: Data.String.IsString a => a

λ> :t (f f) Nothing
(f f) Nothing :: Maybe a

λ> :t (f f) 12.3
(f f) 12.3 :: Fractional a => a

λ> :t (f f) 10000
(f f) 10000 :: Num a => a

λ> :t (f f) f
(f f) f :: a -> a

λ> :t f f f f f f f f f f f f
f f f f f f f f f f f f :: a -> a
```

Ok, now you see that `(f f) x` does not in general have in infinite type,
let's even make this one more example:

```
λ> let g x = f f x
λ> :t g
g :: a -> a
```

Now, `f` is boring, because it has just two implementations:

```
f x = undefined
```

-or-

```
f x = x
```

The **only** terminating implementation of a function with type `(a -> a)` is the later:

```
f x = x
```

That is, a function that just returns the parameter as it is, without even looking at it, let alone doing anything to it...

Why? Hard to understand, but try to think about what `a -> a` promises.

It promises that you can really put **anything** into it now matter what type, and that you are guaranteed to get out a value of the same type.

So all `f` could do to it's parameter in order to *calculate* the result, is something that it must be able to do to **every** type!

E.g. if we would say, that `f` should increment the input, then we could not apply `f` to a e.g. a `Bool`, if we wanted `f` to make *upper case* the input, we could not apply it to something that is not a `String`, etc..

But that we can apply a function with the signature `a -> a` to **any** type is exactly what is promised by that type signature.

So, `f` is basically pretty boring, but **the compiler did not complain about infinite types**, when we were playing around with ghci!

Q: Now, why is it a problem in a function like e.g. `applyTwiceWrong`(see below)?

A: Because the compiler wants to **bind** `a` to **one** type, that satisfies all occurrences in the type signature, and in the inferred types of the (sub-)epxressions in the function body.

Let's look at the error closely:

```
λ> :{
λ| let applyTwiceWrong :: (a -> a) -> a -> a
λ|     applyTwiceWrong f x = f f x
λ| :}

<interactive>:229:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a -> a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          applyTwice :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a -> a
        at <interactive>:228:19
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: f f x
      In an equation for ‘applyTwiceWrong’: applyTwiceWrong f x = f f x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: a (bound at <interactive>:229:18)
        f :: a -> a (bound at <interactive>:229:16)
        applyTwiceWrong :: (a -> a) -> a -> a (bound at <interactive>:229:5)
```

The first bullet point states exactly that:

> (...) `a` is a rigid type variable **bound by the type signature** for: applyTwiceWrong (...)

The **only possible way** to write a type signature for `applyTwiceWrong` involves spooky stuff, i.e. **higher-ranked-types**

Higher ranked types can only be used after activating a compiler extension:

```
λ> :set -XRankNTypes
```

With that we can define a variation of `applyTwiceWrong`, let's call it `applyTwiceBoring`, that has the same *body* but a different type:

```
λ> :{
λ| applyTwiceBoring :: (forall b . b -> b) -> a -> a
λ| applyTwiceBoring f x = (f f) x
λ| :}
λ>
```

We now have the `a` that is used for `x` and the return type of `applyTwiceBoring` we introduced a new variable `b` with `forall b . b -> b`.

`b` may now *vary* between sub-expressions of `applyTwiceBoring`, because in `applyTwiceBoring` **`b` is free**!

Remeber that the sub expressions for `(f f) x` are:

```
            finalResult
                  =
                apply
              /       \
             /         \
            /           \
 intermediateFunction    x
          =
        apply
      /       \
     /         \
    f           f
```

in `intermediateFunction` the `b` will be `b -> b` and in `intermediateFunction x` the `b` will have type `a -> a`.

Now the fact that **the only** terminating function we can pass to `applyTwiceBoring` is `f x = x` is - to say it politely - *limiting*.

### Composition to the rescue!

Now, is all lost?

No! Your intuition behind `(f f) x` is quite good!

The idea behind this is: Let's **compose** `f` with *itself* and then apply *that* to `x`.

Well, in Math and in Haskell **composition** of two functions is done like this: 
         f . g

Which means: apply `f` to the result of `g`

In Haskell there is operator `.`, defined simply as:

```
 (f . g) x = f (g x)
```

and **that** we can use to rescue `(f f) x`, which then becomes:

```
     (f . f) x
```

So the complete functions is:

```
    applyTwice f x = (f . f) x
```

And we prove using *equational reasoning* that this is the same as `f (f x)`:

```
    applyTwice f x = (f . f) x       [insert the definition of . ]
    applyTwice f x = f (f x)         QED
```

Now since Haskell is really awesome, we can write

```
    applyTwice f x = (f . f) x
```

as

```
    applyTwice f = f . f
```

I hope this helps, good luck with your journey ;)

Comment: Why after `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` apply `f ` still continue `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))`?

Comment: @zero_coding Good point, I missed an important aspect. The Answer is because in the function `applyTwice` the `f` is fixed to the type `a -> a` BUT with `a` being whatever `x` is, therefore the type inference ends up building an infinite type. I will improve my answer, please give feedback.

Comment: What I really do not understand is, `f f` is going to apply them self in `applyTwice` function only twice, after applying this is for me `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)` clear. How it comes to `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))` because `x = a`?

Comment: @zero_coding almost, It is like this: if `f :: a -> a` then the expression `f f` forces the type inference to match `a`  with `a -> a`, since the _second_ `f` in `f f` of course also has type `a -> a`, now replace every `a` with `a->a` until infinity and you get, that `a -> a` would have to also match `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)`   and `((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a))` and `(((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a)) -> ((a -> a) -> (a -> a)))` ... etc